# Native lazy-loading (loading=lazy) not working even with flags enabled

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, lazy-loading

I am currently trying to update my Website using the new loading="lazy" attribute as shown here: https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading

As seen in the video, everything works as expected, but compared with my waterfall diagram in chrome, it doesn't.

**How it looks:**
[image: chrome developer tools]

**How it should look:**

[image: chrome developer tools]

This is how its implemented:

```
<img class="has-border" src="https://andreramoncombucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/assets/img/work/personal-website/pw_full.jpg" style="object-fit: cover;" alt="..." loading="lazy">
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Oddly, if I remove my stylesheet completely, lazy loading works as expected. I am curious if you might see the same behavior. EDIT: Turns out my page was not long enough to cause any images to be deferred. I tried on mobile, and it was work as expected.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had a similar issue when trying to implement it.

I use Chrome by default and it was not working. When I tested it in Firefox, it did work. That made me think it was a browser problem.

After digging in a bit more, I found out the "problem" for my case. It might be the same probably for many others.

It turns out **Chrome is more impatient** than Firefox when loading images tagged as lazy. That means it loads the images much earlier, so an image will not be loaded when it appears at the screen but earlier than that.
Firefox, on the other side, is loading the images almost when they are about to be shown at the screen.

The images I was testing were below the fold, but the page was not very long, so Chrome was loading the images anyway.

When I tried it in a much longer article, the images that were deep down the article did load lazily in Chrome as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: From my experimentation, seems that 3200px is about what chrome considers to be "below the fold" for lazy loading purposes.

Comment: On second though, it looks like it's a little more complicated than just a fixed pixel distance https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/#load-in-distance-threshold

Comment: I tested and this answer is true, the image way below the screen viewport is loaded, the detail of the pixel treshold is described in this link:

https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/
Chrome also will change threshold depending on the connection client are using

Comment: Also you can't change the pixel viewing threshold seemingly... https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#can-i-change-how-close-an-image-needs-to-be-before-a-load-is-triggered

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar problem, and after some research, I found the solution:

Just need to add width and height to the **IMG** tag, this is because the browser needs to know the size of the element before applying lazy loading.

Your code:

```
<img class="has-border" src="..." style="object-fit: cover;" alt="..." loading="lazy">
```

Your code after adding width and height:

```
<img class="has-border" src="..." style="object-fit: cover;" alt="..." loading="lazy" width="200px" height="200px">
```

Another alternative is using inline style:

```
<img class="has-border" src="..." style="object-fit:cover; height:200px; width:200px;" alt="..." loading="lazy">
```

Take into consideration I just randomly set the dimensions of the **IMG** tag to 200px.
You can find more information on this [web.dev article](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#images-should-include-dimension-attributes)

hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

There is currently a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1647077) in Firefox: The `loading="lazy"` attribute has no effect, if it is placed after the `src` attribute.

The fix is simple: place the **`loading` attribute before the `src` attribute**.

Working example:

```
<img
  loading="lazy"
  src=...
/>
```

The following will not work in Firefox - images will be loaded immediately (but works in Chrome):

```
<img
  src=...
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. BTW this bug looks super ridiculous :(

Comment: are you sure its a bug? it fixed it for me on chrome

Answer (score 4):

I have the worst reason it wasn't working - I forgot to add the `width` and `height` attributes (they were instead added as `style`s in my broken code)

Comment: this can be a reason since chrome needs to know the exact dimens of the picture to avoid jumps when the images load

Answer (score 2):

optionally if you dont want to change your image size use this

Original code

```
<img class="has-border" src="..." style="object-fit: cover;" alt="..." loading="lazy">
```

With working Lazy load with no size restrictions

```
<img class="has-border" src="..." style="object-fit: cover;" alt="..." loading="lazy" width="auto" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix is just to implement it yourself with an `IntersectionObserver` at the footer of your document.

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const img = entry.target;
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("data-src"));
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
});

//Get images that aren't visible on load
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img").filter((img) => {
  const { top, left, bottom, right } = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    top >= 0 &&
    left >= 0 &&
    bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
});

imgs.forEach((elm) => {
  //Save src to data-src
  elm.setAttribute("data-src", elm.getAttribute("src"));
  //Set src to single invisible base64 pixel to minimize jank
  elm.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
  );
  //Observe the element when it scrolls into the viewport
  observer.observe(elm);
});
```

Make sure you do it in the footer with a SYNCHRONOUS script tag. If you wait for `DOMContentLoaded` or the like, some of the images will have already been requested. E.g.

```html
<html>
<body>
  Your body content, including images...
  <script>
     //PUT YOUR CODE HERE
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice there are no attributes on the script. If your script tag has a `defer` or `async` attribute on it or is of `type='module'` the javascript won't execute until the image downloads have already begun.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of **cache**.

If you see here **lazy-img** in the Network tab that means everything is fine.

You can test on a private window if you want just to double check.

[image]

Answer (score -6):

The image should be positioned as "relative" in style.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.