# loading="lazy" on images not working in Angular 12

Tags: angular, image, lazy-loading, angular12, image-loading

I use loading="lazy" on all offscreen images including footer images. I try this with Client Side Rendering As well as with Server-side Rendering(Angular Universal).

But all the images load initially without scrolling.

```
<img src="{{product.featured_image.mobile}}" alt="" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Maybe this will give some more insights? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753240/native-lazy-loading-loading-lazy-not-working-even-with-flags-enabled

Comment: Its a browser dependent behaviour, try changing your browser, you may see a difference

Comment: I have checked this in chrome and firefox. It didn't work. I have used the same approach on the WordPress website. It works in WordPress.

This is strange but that's not working for me in Angular.

Comment: When you look at the generated source, is the loading attr still there?

Comment: @MikeOne
Yes. The loading attribute is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img [lazyLoad]="product.featured_image.mobile || ''" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**